# How does Google's Files Go give suggestions about data present on my phone

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, recommendation-engine

I use Google Files Go and it suggests me about clearing memes in my phone and also gives other suggestions on the basis of data present on my phone. How does Google do it? Are they constantly monitoring all the data present on my phone?

I would like to know about how they implement the recommendation model.

Answer (score 0):

Files Go app uses [Artificial Intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence) to reduce clutter on your phone. You may find more detail on the "Google's Files Go app uses AI to declutter your phone" [page](https://www.androidcentral.com/googles-files-go-app-uses-ai-declutter-your-phone).